# MySQL db not working on Python 2.7 Raspberry Pi3

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I have found the code below as I want to print on an interval readings from BME280 to a MySQL database. Whenever I try to run below code it gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_BME280/sensor.py", line 7, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
    module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I have installed the Mariadb and the python connectors etc. What might be the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  

import os  
import time  
import datetime  
import glob  
import MySQLdb  
from time import strftime  
from Adafruit_BME280 import *  

sensor = BME280(t_mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8, p_mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8, h_mode=BME280_OSAMPLE_8)  

#Variables for MySQL  
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="karolk87", db="sensor") # replace password with your password  
cur = db.cursor()  

def dateTime(): #get UNIX time  
        secs = float(time.time())  
        secs = secs*1000  
        return secs  

def tempRead(): #read temperature, return float with 3 decimal places  
        degrees = float('{0:.3f}'.format(sensor.read_temperature()))  
        return degrees  

def pressRead():#read pressure, return float with 3 decimal places  
        pascals = float('{0:.3f}'.format(sensor.read_pressure()/100))  
        return pascals  

def humidityRead(): #read humidity, return float with 3 decimal places  
        humidity = float('{0:.3f}'.format(sensor.read_humidity()))  
        return humidity  

secs = dateTime()  
temperature = tempRead()  
pressure = pressRead()  
humidity = humidityRead()  

sql = ("""INSERT INTO bmesensor (datetime,temperature,pressure,humidity) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (secs, temperature, pressure, humidity))  

try:  
    print ("Writing to the database...")  
    cur.execute(*sql)  
    db.commit()  
    print ("Write complete")  

except:  
    db.rollback()  
    print ("We have a problem")  

cur.close()  
db.close()  

print (secs)  
print (temperature)  
print (pressure)  
print (humidity)
```

Comment: How did you install the python connector (MySQLdb)? Your backtrace appears to be running Python3, is MySQLdb for python3 installed?

Comment: I checked and my Pi is running Python 2.7. I did sudo apt-get install python-mysql.connector.
Maybe this is overcomplicated code. I have another program that returns he sensor readings with print statement. Maybe there is easier way to copy this to DB and add timestamp?

Comment: Your backtrace lists `python3` indicating its more likely py3 than py2.7. Databases can do timestamps automaticly in columns however you still need the connection going. You could do a `virtualenv` and `pip install python-mysql`

Comment: I see what you mean. How come backtrace gives python 3 and when I run python version check it gives me Python 2.7.x.x?